# Dynamic property lookup handlebars each loop

Tags: json, handlebars.js

Can i have the property i want to loop through come from my data?

```
{{#each (lookup . 'reference')}}
    <li>{{this.text}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Doesn't seem to work, just wondering if this someone else has done this in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find an existing way of doing it so i created a custom each helper that does the job. To avoid any confusion i'm using precompiled grunt handlebars https://github.com/patrickkettner/grunt-compile-handlebars but the script should work with some slight modification in the invoking with addHandlebarHelper.

Gist - https://gist.github.com/mikemellor11/9b23a0af217a3c67593c

```
module.exports = function (path, context, option) {
    var ret = "";

    if(!option){
        option = context;
        context = option.data.root;
    }

    context = getProperty(path, context);

    for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
        option.data.index = i;
        option.data.first = i === 0;
        option.data.last = i === (j - 1);

        ret = ret + option.fn(context[i]);
    }

    return ret;
};


function getProperty( propertyName, object ) {
    var parts = propertyName.split( "." ),
        length = parts.length,
        i,
        property = object || this;

    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        property = property[parts[i]];
    }

    return property;
}
```